# Grayscale doesn't seem to be working, even with proper confidence

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time


dir = 'ingame/'
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    test = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(dir + 'test2.png',grayscale=False,confidence=.7)
    if test:
        print('found')
```

This is the code I'm running, I have the same image, with and without grayscale. Pyautogui still detects the grayscale image with a confidence of 70%, even with grayscale set to false...

1[https://imgur.com/a/gJWhC6R ]
2[https://imgur.com/a/QkE7oAA]

Comment: That's not a surprise.  The grayscale version of an image is still statistically MUCH closer to the RGB version of that image than random screen space.   If you want a color match, set the confidence higher.

Comment: trying that now, I didn't know that, thank you

Comment: Thanks, Robert, you've not only fixed my current problem but prevented future headaches.  You've saved me more time than you can imagine, even with a 100% confidence level...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(5)
image = 'overwatch.png'
loc = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, grayscale=False, confidence=.3)
print (loc)
```

output

```
Box(left=405, top=778, width=88, height=93)
```

but as Tim said above it's more complicated with grayscale than in RGB mode

Comment: nice pfp, appreciate the attempt 4  helping. At around 800 lines, pyautogui fondation